# iPhone 7 iOS 10.3.3 Contact missing after logging into iMessage on Mac

Tags: mac, iphone, contacts, icloud

I have an iPhone 7 with iOS 10.3.3 and after I login to iMessage on my mac, alot of my contacts are missing, but the funny thing is, if search for the name in iMessage on the iphone the contact appears, however it does not appear on iMessage on my mac when search for name.

How do I get these missing contacts back? They appear not to be gone forever as I can still search for them in iMessage on my iPhone.

Comment: Do you synchronise your contacts with iCloud?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: Settings > iCloud > Contacts is switched on?

Answer (score 1):

I accidentially figured this out myself poking around with the same issue. My contacts are stored on my company's servers. So I changed the default contacts to my iPad and this fixed the issue. I then put my contact default back to my company's server and it still works.

Go to Settings > Contacts 
Look at the Default Account value and note what it is. You will need this for the last steo.
Change the Default Account (hopefully you have more than one) to iPad
- Or, just switch it to someting other than what it is.
Check your messages and see if the names show up instead of phone numbers
Go back to Contacts and put the default back to whatever it was orginally.

This worked for me, hope it works for others. 
Good Luck